# How to make HTML Tags possible to accept in Textarea in mvc Razor?? Or which other controls should i use to do that?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Hello guys,

I have created one textarea in my application.

And now i want to add HTML tags in my textarea and want to accept it using following tag

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PageTitle, new { style = "Width:500px; maxlength=500;" })
```

It doesn't allow HTML code but the simple text.
        So what should i do for that???

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't allow it? You can't type <strong>test</strong> in your textarea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

apply the following attribute to the property `PageTitle`:

```
[AllowHtml]
public string PageTitle { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Create a custom EditorTemplate, but that involves also
2. Use `@Html.TextBox` which does have the overload to use custom HTML attributes.

This is assuming you meant attributes and not tags as your example code implies.